# SubSonic Save() changes not working

Tags: vb.net, subsonic2.2

I am trying to save changes to a record, however I am getting the error

> Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint
>   'PK_TStoreAssignment'. Cannot insert
>   duplicate key in object 'TAssignment'.
>   The statement has been terminated.

Here is the subsonic query

```
Dim current = DB.Select().From(TStoreAssignment.Schema) _
                                 .Where("assignmentID").IsEqualTo(selectedRow.AssignmentID) _
                                 .ExecuteSingle(Of TStoreAssignment)()

'Modify the sequence
 current.ManualSequence = 999
 current.Save()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two possibilities for this error:

- Either `ManualSequence` is (part of) the primary key of `TStoreAssignment`, and you already have an other entry with 999
- or (probably) SubSonic thinks `current` is a new object and tries to insert it instead of updating it when you call `Save()`. You can debug and check the `IsNew`property. If that's the case, you may call `MarkOld()` before the `Save` method. Or even better, use something like:

  ```
  DB.Update().From(Of TStoreAssignment)() _
      .Set(TStoreAssignment.ManualSequenceColumn).EqualTo(999) _
      .Where(TStoreAssignment.AssignementIDColumn).IsEqualTo(selectedRow.AssignmentID) _
      .Execute()
  ```